# The reason for using @ in the razor extension attributes

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor, attributes

Both of these codes have the same result in the final markup. so why is the **@** used in the htmlAttributes section?

```
@Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.ManagerName, new { @autocomplete = "off", @maxlength = "40" })

@Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.ManagerName, new { autocomplete = "off", maxlength = "40" })
```

Does the MVC version have an effect on this?
It may have been mandatory in older versions!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the "new { ... }" block, some words such as "class" are keywords. @ is required in order to escape the keyword. For non-keywords, it doesn't make a difference.